# Firebase connection create user error on Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

ı try a create user on firebase with kotlin. but i get the error toast all the time 
     Theese are my imports:

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_create_user.*
```

here the rest of my code
    class createUser : AppCompatActivity() {
   private var fbsignup: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_user)

    submitButton.setOnClickListener {
        val email = userSaveText.text.toString().trim()
        val password = passSaveText.text.toString().trim()

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "enter a mail ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return@setOnClickListener
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return@setOnClickListener
        }


    fbsignup.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { task ->

        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "succesfully created account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return@addOnCompleteListener
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "errore!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return@addOnCompleteListener
        }

    }}
}
```

What am i supposed to do?

Comment: The [sample in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account) contains `Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());`, which will log the cause of the failure.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry but i dont know java and stiil i dont how to fix this problem on Kotlin code :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to remove `return  @setOnClickListener` and return
   `@addOnCompleteListener` from if statements
2. try to initiate firebaseAuth like this:

```
private  lateinit var fbsignup:FirebaseAuth
```

(before on create method)

And after on create method like this:

```
fbsignup=FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
```